# Time complexity of JavaConverters asScala method

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

Starting with Scala version 2.9 there exists a handy converter to convert from `java.util.List` and other collections to Scala's data structures by writing something like this:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
def scalaVersion = callJavaMethod.asScala
```

This is a lovely little feature, as it allows one to exploit the advantages of Scala when interacting with existing Java code.

However, I am uncertain about the involved time and space complexity and could not find anything in the official documentation, hence, the following question:

Where can I get information on the complexity (time and space) of the JavaConverters?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Various `JavaConverters` classes are using [*Adapter*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) pattern to wrap original Java collection (`underlying`) and provide Scala interface. Thus both converting and accessing converted collections is constant in time (`O(1)`) introducing only minor overhead.

For instance this is the full source code of [`JListWrapper`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.8.0/scala/collection/JavaConversions$$JListWrapper.html):

```
case class JListWrapper[A](val underlying : java.util.List[A]) extends mutable.Buffer[A] {
    def length = underlying.size
    override def isEmpty = underlying.isEmpty
    override def iterator : Iterator[A] = underlying.iterator
    def apply(i : Int) = underlying.get(i)
    def update(i : Int, elem : A) = underlying.set(i, elem)
    def +=:(elem : A) = { underlying.subList(0, 0).add(elem) ; this } 
    def +=(elem : A): this.type = { underlying.add(elem); this }
    def insertAll(i : Int, elems : Traversable[A]) = { val ins = underlying.subList(0, i) ;  elems.seq.foreach(ins.add(_)) }
    def remove(i : Int) = underlying.remove(i)
    def clear = underlying.clear
    def result = this
}
```

Also note that converting Java collection to Scala and then back to Java yields the original collection, not double-wrapper.

Comment: `JListWrapper` is from `JavaConversions`, not `JavaConverters`. Is there any document where these relations, including the constant time, is given? I cannot find anything about that in the API doc.

Comment: @Frank: `.asScala` from `JavaConverters` uses `JListWrapper` from `JavaConversions`. Unfortunately I cannot find anything documenting time complexity.

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept it for the lack of other answers, though I'm a bit disappointed that none of that is documented at all.

Comment: Feel free to open an issue, I think this should have been in the Scaladoc.