# Scala Array[String] to Java Collection[String]

Tags: scala

I have a Scala array of strings:

```
val names:Array[String] = something.map(...)
```

I need to call an Android(java) [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20T%3E%29) that accepts a Collection

```
public void addAll (Collection<? extends T> collection)
```

How do I covert the Array to a Collection?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Java approach:

```
java.util.Arrays.asList(names: _*)
```

### Scala approach:

```
import collection.JavaConversions._

val namesColl: java.util.Collection[String] = names.toSeq
```

In the latter approach `names` array is first converted to `Seq[String]` and then an implicit conversion located in `JavaConversions` figures out that Java collection is needed so it applies necessary transformation trasparently. Don't worry, [it is constant in time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517636).

Comment: Thanks, but what do you mean by "Java approach"?

Comment: @Steve: I added the "*Scala approach*" as well :-).

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the explanation.  Any reason why you would choose one over the other?

Comment: @Steve Use Java approach. It has less overhead.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral: As far as I can tell `Arrays.asList` creates one wrapper while `toSeq` and implicit conversion - two. In both cases there is no copying of an array, hence constant time complexity. So the difference is minimal, but I agree.

Comment: Thanks guys. Your answers are always helpful. It can be difficult fully grasping Scala, especially Scala-Java interaction.

Comment: Please, can you explain what is the logic behind the " _* ", it works but I don't understand.
When you type "name:" I guess that you are operating over names, with a sort of dynamic collection, and then you return it, right?
What is exactly "names: _*" returning? if Java Arrays are the same as Scala arrays why doen't work directly?

Answer (score 4):

`JavaConversions` is now deprecated.
You should use `JavaConverters` instead.

```
import collection.JavaConverters.asJavaCollection
val collection = asJavaCollection(Array("some value"))
```