# Java program convert to scala the interoperability problems

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

Here java list convertion  errors are occured

**Scala Code**

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
  @Override
  def getAllStudents():List[Student] = {
    return getSession().createQuery("from Student where isDelete =  'false' ")
    .list()  **here error occured and that shows below **
     }
```

here i import this statement but no change

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
```

**Error**
type mismatch; found : java.util.List[?0] where type ?0 required: 
 scala.collection.immutable.List[com.model.domain.entity.Student]

**The Java Code**

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Student> getAllStudents() {
        return getSession().createQuery(
                "from Student where isDelete =  'false' ").list();
    }
```

Comment: Where you have placed `import scala.collection.JavaConverters._`?

Comment: @om-nom-nom top of program...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your own answer is incorrect. Instead, if you are implementing an interface (or extending a class) which needs to return a Java list, you should do this:

```
def getAllStudents() : java.util.List[Student] = {
  getSession().createQuery("from Student where isDelete =  'false' ")
    .list()
 }
```

If you *don't* need Java list here, then you should instead do

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

def getAllStudents() : Seq[Student] = {
  getSession().createQuery("from Student where isDelete =  'false' ")
    .list().asScala
 }
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that if you use `JavaConverters` to convert let's say a `java.util.List` to a `Seq` and later back to a `java.util.List`, it remembers the original list and yields it at the later conversion. See [Time complexity of JavaConverters asScala method](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8517636/1333025).